# MongoDB update and insert on an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document as shown below :

```
{
  "ITEMS": [
    {
      "BUKRS": "1000",
      "GLACC": "476000",
      "NETWR": 100
    }
  ],
  "EXCEPTIONS": [
    {
      "CURR": true,
      "EVENT": "WEB",
      "DATE_TIME": "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
    },
    {
      "CURR": true,
      "EVENT": "WEB",
      "DATE_TIME": "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
    },
    {
      "CURR": false,
      "EVENT": "WEB",
      "DATE_TIME": "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need to achieve is in one mongo query, set all `EXCEPTIONS.$.CURR:false` and insert a new object into **EXCEPTIONS** array with mostly `CURR : true`.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: MongoDB version is 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one DB call using [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) for MongoDB version's >= `3.2` :

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([{
    updateOne: {
        "filter": {}, // If you've any filters to match a doc give it here
        "update": { $set: { "EXCEPTIONS.$[].CURR": false } } // $[] operator updates all elements in an array.
    }
}, {
    updateOne: {
        "filter": {},
        "update": {
            $push: {
                "EXCEPTIONS": {
                    "CURR": true,
                    "EVENT": "WEB",
                    "DATE_TIME": "New_Time"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**Document in DB :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e475da77f8bc30a7504f0b6"),
    "ITEMS" : [ 
        {
            "BUKRS" : "1000",
            "GLACC" : "476000",
            "NETWR" : 100
        }
    ],
    "EXCEPTIONS" : [ 
        {
            "CURR" : true,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }, 
        {
            "CURR" : true,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }, 
        {
            "CURR" : false,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "deletedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedCount" : 0.0,
    "matchedCount" : 2.0, // It's 2 as it modified array/doc twice
    "upsertedCount" : 0.0,
    "insertedIds" : {},
    "upsertedIds" : {}
}
```

**Result in DB :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e475da77f8bc30a7504f0b6"),
    "ITEMS" : [ 
        {
            "BUKRS" : "1000",
            "GLACC" : "476000",
            "NETWR" : 100
        }
    ],
    "EXCEPTIONS" : [ 
        {
            "CURR" : false,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }, 
        {
            "CURR" : false,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }, 
        {
            "CURR" : false,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "2020-02-08T22:46:29.219Z"
        }, 
        {
            "CURR" : true,
            "EVENT" : "WEB",
            "DATE_TIME" : "New_Time"
        }
    ]
}
```